# i not get dynamsoft ResourcesPath

Tags: java, vue.js, nuxt.js, dwt, dynamsoft

`Dynamsoft.DWT.ResourcesPath = "dwt-resources"`

Packege.json

```json
"scripts": {
  "dev": "ncp node_modules/dwt/dist static/dwt-resources && nuxt",
  "build": "nuxt build",
  "start": "nuxt start",
  "generate": "nuxt generate && ncp node_modules/dwt/dist dist/dwt-resources"
}
```

I use framwork nuxt js but error get path.

Comment: Alright, please give us more context and debugging info than just this please. What even is `dwt-resources`?

Answer (score 0):

The resource folder is located at the root directory of the project.

So change

```
Dynamsoft.DWT.ResourcesPath = "dwt-resources"
```

to

```
Dynamsoft.DWT.ResourcesPath = "/dwt-resources"
```